# Does anyone know of anywhere I can download php 7.2 for MAMP pro 3.5?

Tags: php, mamp-pro

They have now added an option to download additional php versions from within the MAMP app itself and have removed the option to directly download php versions.

The links to php versions via the way back machine no longer works.

Comment: Is that version not available when using the MAMP Pro gui - as per information detailed here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5JZ3PSGj81E ??

Comment: Not available in MAMP 3.5 unfortunately

Comment: did you manage to do it?

Comment: No, I had to upgrade my MAMP.